# Is it possible output audio from a laptop to a desktop using an HDMI cable so the desktop can then process/play the audio input from the HDMI cable?

Tags: windows, laptop, audio, hdmi

I'm mute, but I would like to talk while I stream. To do this, I wish to use a TTS program while I play. Since it would be obnoxiously inconvenient to switch windows while gaming, I'd like to hook up my laptop to my computer so that my laptop may be used as a dedicated TTS device. I'd like to send audio from the laptop through the HDMI cable into the PC, and from there it would go through OBS to be streamed. I only have an HDMI cable at the moment.

Comment: What is the TTS program?

Comment: Does it have to be an HDMI cable? You can stream audio between computers via network, there are commercial and free programs for this, and there are also "virtual soundcards" you could use as input while gaming.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC has an HDMI capture card or USB device, then this should be straightforward to achieve:

- Laptop Out → PC In.

Without a capture device, this won't be possible. **Note:** even with a capture device, you may have issues getting just the audio from it, without video too.

HDMI typically carries audio and video from one device to another, from "*source*" to "*sink*" - both in the same direction. HDMI does support [ARC (Audio Return Channel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#HDMI_Ethernet_and_Audio_Return_Channel) that allows audio to travel *upstream* back to the source device, however this tends to only be supported by TVs and [AVRs (Audio Video Receivers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV_receiver).

---

A better option might be one of the following:

- Use a second "*host*" application on your laptop - so that PC and Laptop are both presenting the stream (depends on your streaming solution)
- Use the analog audio out into "*line in*" on your PC - It'll probably be blue, if you have one
- Use something like VLC / Ventrilo / Mumble / TeamSpeak to transmit the rendered audio from Laptop to PC via the network - this will require driver support on the laptop (e.g: allowing use of the "*Mix*" as a souce)